# How to use rails bundler behind a proxy network?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, proxy

I am using ubuntu 12.04. I am trying to run

```
bundle install
```

behind the proxy network of my institute.I have correctly setup the apt.conf file and all other downloads from terminal are working fine. I added the following to ~/.bashrc

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://user:password@proxy_url:port
alias curl="curl -x http://proxy_url:port/ -U user:password"
alias rvm="rvm --proxy http://user:password@proxy_url:port"
```

And i added the following to my environment file:

```
http_proxy="http://user:password@proxy_url:port/"
https_proxy="https://user:password@proxy_url:port/"
ftp_proxy="ftp://user:password@proxy_url:port/"
socks_proxy="socks://user:password@proxy_url:port/"
```

I also added the following to ~/.gemrc:

```
http-proxy:http://user:password@proxy_url:port
```

After making all these changes when i run the bundler using with or without sudo on the terminal i get back the source code of some html page.The code of html page is followed by the line:

```
Net::HTTPProxyAuthenticationRequired:
```

Please tell me what to do to make rails run behind the proxy.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a Rails question per-se, it's a Bundler question.

I would try the following on the command line (either should work):

`export HTTP_PROXY=http://user:password@proxy_url:port`

`export http_proxy=http://user:password@proxy_url:port`

Potentially your `~/.bashrc` file isn't being executed on login/etc.

I would also change the `~/.gemrc` file to: `http_proxy=http://user:password@proxy_url:port`

Check out the source code in [Bundler](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/e647b5f8fe84ef54d4999b2f65ba37253caeb088/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent.rb#L895) for any extra information you may need.

Comment: Still getting the same error.I first did the export command and then did bundle install.I have also updated my gemrc file.

Comment: Ok - so the last thing I can recommend in trying is: `HTTP_PROXY=http://user:password@proxy_url:port bundle install`.